# How to convert binary code to a number in Dart

Tags: dart

Given an array of ones and zeroes, convert the equivalent binary value to an integer.

Eg: [0, 0, 0, 1] is treated as 0001 which is the binary representation of 1.

- Testing: [0, 0, 0, 1] ==> 1
- Testing: [0, 0, 1, 0] ==> 2
- Testing: [0, 1, 0, 1] ==> 5
- Testing: [1, 0, 0, 1] ==> 9
- Testing: [0, 0, 1, 0] ==> 2
- Testing: [0, 1, 1, 0] ==> 6
- Testing: [1, 1, 1, 1] ==> 15
- Testing: [1, 0, 1, 1] ==> 11

With Prime numbers I solved everything code from below

```html
int binaryArrayToNumber(List<int> arr) {
  return 
    (arr[0] * 8) +
    (arr[1] * 4) +
    (arr[2] * 2) +
    (arr[3] * 1);
    
}
```

How do I make this automatic for larger numbers

Answer (score 0):

A traditional approach would be to iterate over the binary digits and to perform bitshifts and ORs:

```dart
int binaryArrayToNumber(List<int> digits) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var digit in digits) {
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digit;
  }
  return result;
}
```

A more concise, less error-prone (but less efficient) approach would be to convert the list of digits to a `String` and then parse it:

```dart
int binaryArrayToNumber(List<int> digits) =>
    int.parse(digits.join(""), radix: 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's good to learn the protocols for the core data types, like List.fold.

```
int binaryArrayToNumber(List<int> digits) =>
  digits.fold(0,(prev, cur) => 2*prev + cur);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int binaryArrayToNumber(List<int> arr) {
    return int.parse(arr.join(''), radix: 2); }

print(binaryArrayToNumber([1, 1, 1, 1])); // 15
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.